# Uploading Image to DB with Dynamic Data LinQ-to-SQL Web Site

Tags: asp.net, database, image, linq-to-sql, dynamic

I'm just now created Dynamic Data LINQ to SQL Web Site. And I have got a problem with image type. for all sql data types generated html elements by fieldTemplate. So, how can I create fieldtemplate for image-view, and image-upload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good link with video:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2008/04/09/sample-for-displaying-images-updated-screencast.aspx

if codeFile.ascx.cs doesn't recognize ID Controls. You need to create your own .ascx files and to copy all code from .ascx files in ZIP to your files.